# Git subtree push can't find local file

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-subtree

I'm using subtrees to share an SDK between a number of projects. When I try to push the subtree from one of my projects, I'm getting the following error. I'm using this command:

```
git subtree push --prefix <prefix> <repo> master --squash
git push using: <repo> master

open <repo-path>\SDK\Plugins\<file>.dll: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

In this case, < repo-path > is incorrect. It is the path to the root repository and not the file itself. It should be looking for:

```
<repo-path>\<prefix>\SDK\Plugins\<file>.dll
```

It's as though the push is ignoring the prefix. This command works fine in other repos.

One possible explanation is that this repo was using LFS for the dlls. That said, I've disabled LFS for these files, but I'm still getting the error.

I'm totally stumped on this. I can just hand-copy the subtree to a project that's working, but I'd like to try to understand what's going on.